# Hosting PHP application on Centos 7 (AWS EC2)

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, centos7

I am trying to setup an existing PHP application. Moved form an external host onto AWS, it's on an EC2 instance with Centos 7.

The folder structure provided by the current host looks like this:
[image]

I can FTP and SSH into the EC2 instance. But where should I put this folder and what setup is required to point the website to the folder?

EC2 from FTP:
[image]

Comment: Have you installed Apache/Nginx/PHP on your server? Put your website in the www folder as configured in your webserver

Comment: Apache/PHP/Mysql are seutp on the server, but the above is all the folders I have.

Comment: Do you have ssh access? the steps roughly are: 1. locate your webroot, 2. place there a PHP fine with phpinfo() 3. check the configuration and compare it to the previous host, 5. modify php.ini to your liking, upload your site/db. 6. Check if all works as intended